# using an array to create a string

Tags: java, arrays, split

I'm having an issue with some of my code.  I'm receiving a date in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format as a string called `dateofQ`.

I want the date to be `yyyy_mm_dd`, I'm using a `string.split()` into an array, but it wont return the 3rd array called myArr[3]:

```
String[] myArr = dateofQ.split("\\/");
String dateFormat = String.format("%s_%s_%s",myArr[2],myArr[1],myArr[0]);
```

It returns `myArr[1]` and `myArr[0]`, but when I also add `myArr[3]` I get an issue at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:34)
```

Comment: Sample input plz! I mean what did you give in dateofQ

Comment: I have tried your code and it works for me. Are you sure that the date really has the dd/mm/yyy format?

Comment: Uh. Guys. Again, the OP edited this to read `myArray[2]` instead of `myArr[3]`, but someone else was also editing it and it overwrote his edit. :-\.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the array only has 3 elements, and `myArr[3]` is trying to get the *fourth* element (remember, arrays are zero-indexed).

To get the third element, use `myArr[2]`.

Comment: He edited it to refer to `myArr[2]` right as you posted this.

Comment: Actually, someone else edited it while he was editing it and overwrote his change, so I put it back in.

Comment: Array index happens at `2` index so this is not a solution to his problem.

Comment: Well, the OP **does** say myArr[3]. The OP edited this to say myArr[2], but someone was also editing his post at the same time and overwrote his changes. I edited that back in, but it hasn't been accepted as an edit yet.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the length of `myArr` is at most 2.

Please check to ensure `myArr.length` is not at least 3.

Inserting

```
System.out.println(myArr.length);
```

right after:

```
String[] myArr = dateofQ.split("\\/");
```

is an easy way to check this.

Comment: He should check the length Array Index happened at 2 so there are not enough elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably missing something really obvious, but couldn't you just do something like...

```
try {
    String dateofQ = "08/03/1972";
    SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");

    dateofQ = out.format(in.parse(dateofQ));
    System.out.println(dateofQ);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which out puts `1972_03_08`

Comment: Thanks this did it.  I've never heard of SimpleDateFormat before (I am a noob). I did need to add import java.text.SimpleDataFormat and import java.text.ParseException to get it to work.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2` This error means you have array of size less than 3 elements and you are trying to access third. i.e. you will get error @ **`myArr[2]`**.

What you should do is you should check length of array first and then access it. If invalid array reject it.

```
if(myArr.length==3)//Process else you need to reject
```

A better way could be use way specified in **MadPorgrammer's** answer.